# Perl: how to compare array to hash and print out results

Tags: perl

I'm quite new to Perl, so I'm sorry if this is somewhat rudimentary.

I'm working with a Perl script that is working as a wrapper for some Python, text formatting, etc. and I'm struggling to get my desired output.

The script takes a folder, for this example, the folder contains 6 text files (test1.txt through test6.txt).  The script then extracts some information from the files, runs a series of command line programs and then outputs a tab-delimited result.  However, that result contains only those results that made it through the rest of the processing by the script, i.e. the result.

Here are some snippets of what I have so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

## create array to capture all of the file names from the folder
opendir(DIR, $folder) or die "couldn't open $folder: $!\n";
my @filenames = grep { /\.txt$/ } readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;

#here I run some subroutines, the last one looks like this
my $results = `blastn -query $shortname.fasta -db DB/$db -outfmt "6 qseqid sseqid score evalue" -max_target_seqs 1`;
#now I would like to compare what is in the @filenames array with $results
```

Example of tab delimited result - stored in `$results`:

```
test1.txt    200    1:1-20      79     80
test3.txt    800    1:1-200     900    80
test5.txt    900    1:1-700     100    2000
test6.txt    600    1:1-1000    200    70
```

I would like the final output to include all of the files that were run through the script, so I think I need a way to compare two arrays or perhaps compare an array to a hash?

Example of the desired output:

```
test1.txt    200    1:1-20      79     80
test2.txt    0      No result
test3.txt    800    1:1-200     900    80
test4.txt    0      No result
test5.txt    900    1:1-700     100    2000
test6.txt    600    1:1-1000    200    70
```

**Update**

Ok, so I got this to work with suggestions by @terdon by reading the file into a hash and then comparing.  So I was trying to figure out how to do this with out writing to file and the reading the file back in - I still can't seem to get the syntax correct.  Here's what I have, however it seems like I'm not able to match the array to the hash - meaning the hash must not be correct:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#create variable to mimic blast results
my $blast_results = "file1.ab1  9   350 0.0 449 418 418 403479  403042  567
file3.ab1   2   833 0.0 895 877 877 3717226 3718105 984";

#create array to mimic filename array
my @filenames = ("file1.ab1", "file2.ab1", "file3.ab1");

#header for file
my $header = "Query\tSeq_length\tTarget found\tScore (Bits)\tExpect(E-value)\tAlign-length\tIdentities\tPositives\tChr\tStart\tEnd\n";

#initialize hash
my %hash;
#split blast results into array
my @row = split(/\s+/, $blast_results);
$hash{$row[0]}=$_;
print $header;
foreach my $file (@filenames){
    ## If this filename has an associated entry in the hash, print it
    if(defined($hash{$file})){
        print "$row[0]\t$row[9]\t$row[1]:$row[7]-$row[8]\t$row[2]\t$row[3]\t$row[4]\t$row[5]\t$row[6]\t$row[1]\t$row[7]\t$row[8]\n";
        }
    ## If not, print this.
    else{
        print "$file\t0\tNo Blast Results: Sequencing Rxn Failed\n";
        }
    }
print "-----------------------------------\n";      
print "$blast_results\n"; #test what results look like
print "-----------------------------------\n"; 
print "$row[0]\t$row[1]\n"; #test if array is getting split correctly
print "-----------------------------------\n"; 
print "$filenames[2]\n"; #test if other array present
```

The result from this script is (the `@filenames` array is not matching the hash):

```
Query   Seq_length  Target found    Score (Bits)    Expect(E-value) Align-length    Identities  Positives   Chr Start   End
file1.ab1   0   No Blast Results: Sequencing Rxn Failed
file2.ab1   0   No Blast Results: Sequencing Rxn Failed
file3.ab1   0   No Blast Results: Sequencing Rxn Failed
-----------------------------------
file1.ab1   9   350 0.0 449 418 418 403479  403042  567
file3.ab1   2   833 0.0 895 877 877 3717226 3718105 984
-----------------------------------
file1.ab1   9
-----------------------------------
file3.ab1
```

Comment: Your `awk` command does not compare, it prints. Do you need the script to compare them or do you want to print them and do the comparison yourself?

Comment: I would like the perl script to compare them - basically print out the desired output as I don't want to compare them after. Thanks.

Comment: @jpalmer: I found your question very difficult to understand, and have edited it. I still have many questions, but please check that it still properly desctribes your problem and roll back if necessary. I had a problem with the Perl code as the braces don't balance. Where does `$folder` come from?

Comment: @jpalmer: You say, *"The array `@filenames` is the first column of the text file,"* but it isn't — it's a list of all the `*.txt` files in the directory `$folder`, and is defined by the statement `my @filenames = grep { /\.txt$/ } readdir DIR;`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - it's due to my ignorance and lack of understanding of perl - trying to get better.  I've updated the question - hopefully that is more clear?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure what you need here but the equivalent of awk's `A[$1]=$0` is done using hashes in Perl. Something like:

```perl
my %hash;
## Open the output file
open(my $fh, "<","text_file");
while(<$fh>){
    ## remove newlines
    chomp;
    ## split the line
    my @A=split(/\s+/);
    ## Save this in a hash whose keys are the 1st fields and whose
    ## values are the associated lines. 
    $hash{$A[0]}=$_;
}
close($fh);
## Now, compare the file to @filenames
foreach my $file (@filenames){
    ## Print the file name
    print "$file\t";
    ## If this filename has an associated entry in the hash, print it
    if(defined($hash{$file})){
        print "$hash{$file}\n";
    }
    ## If not, print this.
    else{
        print "0\tNo result\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear.  the output from the previous portion of the script is a tab delimited text file that looks like file1.txt (above).  So I think I just need to load those data into a hash and then compare the array to the hash - does that make more sense?

Comment: @jpalmer oh, you want it the other way around. Have a look at the updated answer. I have no idea why you would want to save to a file first and then compare. Since all this data is generated by the script, it makes more sense to compare directly but that's up to you.

Comment: @terdon: I don't think you're doing any favours by guessing at the OP's requirement. It may be a way to get some Stack Overflow points, but it's not a great way to answer a question.

Comment: @Borodin I think I understand which is why I posted the answer. I migrated the question away from where they'd originally posted so I figured it was the least I could do. I have to say that I resent your thinly veiled accusation of rep mongering though. All I did was try to help a user that I'd sent away from the site I moderate. Sheesh!

Comment: @terdon you are right - I don't have to save it as a text file, this was just what I was doing before.  The output of my last subroutine produces a tab delimited result - which I can store in a variable or array?

Comment: @terdon: I thought my accusation was quite explicit. But if you felt obliged to post *something* just because you instigated the migration then perhaps I can understand, although there was no obligation. Your answer should at least have explained your interpretation of the OP's question before answering it. At present I think the biggest problem is that the OP hasn't clarified the question themselves, so leaping to a decision and answering *that* doesn't help too much.

Comment: @jpalmer yes but please don't do this kind of thing in comments. Post a new question with your new requirements if you need to but questions here are expected to be short and succinct.

Comment: @Borodin lol, yes indeed it was explicit. I was trying to give you the benefit of the doubt is all. Call me Mr. Nice Guy. I honestly don't care about SO rep, I don't hang out here much. Anyway, as I said, I think I understood what they needed. I'm not sure but I'm sure enough to post an answer. You seem to take offense at my trying to help somebody. Fine, that's your call and, presumably, your downvote. Let's just leave it at that shall we?

Comment: @terdon Ok, so it is better to just start a new question then to edit this one to make it more clear?  I think I have a better understanding now of what to ask.

Comment: @jpalmer depends. In general, if your edit invalidates existing answers, it is better to post a new question. Otherwise, editing is always better. In this particular case, since the only answer is mine, just let me know and I'll delete it if it is no longer relevant.

Comment: @terdon: The problem I have with your post should be clear: I believe you have prematurely answered a question before *anyone* — including, I believe, the OP—knew what the question was. I think your efforts should have been spent in comments that refined the question rather than offering an answer that resolved your first guess about the problem. Note that your first attempt was wrong: *"oh, you want it the other way around"* and I think that the OP still has only a partial solution. That isn't how it should be.

Comment: @Borodin agreed, no argument there. I thought I'd understood the first time and I think I understand now. What I'm saying is that I'm not _guessing_ as such, I honestly believe I have understood the question. Largely because of the `awk` snippet. Note that I also asked the OP to let me know if their edit shows me that I haven't at which point I'll happily delete this. Anyway, you make a good point and that would have been evident sooner had you expressed yourself in a friendlier way. I know you guys on SO have a serious rep-wh. issue but try and give people the benefit of the doubt next time.

Comment: @terdon: Sadly yes, I believe there is a competition issue here. But my frame of mind hasn't changed since my original comment, and I still think your answer is lacking. No solution should begin *"I'm not entirely sure what you need here"*, and it shouldn't rely on being supplemented by your own comments. Stack Overflow isn't a forum, but a library of solutions to common programming problems.

Comment: @terdon: Thanks for the help.  I was able to make it work for me by using your example.  Am I supposed to post the code that worked?

Comment: @jpalmer up to you. I suspect, however, that that would involve posting your whole program since the details will depend on how your subroutines communicate. If you think it can help others, post it but it is not necessary, no.

Comment: @terdon:  I tried your suggestion to leave the results in a variable, then compare, and then print out the desired output.  However, I can't get the hash table created correctly - is the `while` loop required?

Comment: @jpalmer the `while` is there to read the input file. I can't help you without seeing your code. Why don't you just post a new question with this issue?

Comment: @terdon: Ok, I can post a new question if that is easier, I have re-written the code (probably what I should have asked in the first place) and entered it as an Update to this question.